Micronaut Bean Not Found on Websphere
I have a grails 5.3.6 application running on java 8_261.
I am using Intellij ultimate with grails, groovy and spring plugins.
Whenever I do grails run-app, the app launches normally and opens in my browser (Grails 5.3.6 came automatically with tomcat plugin)
Upon compiling the app into a war file using grails war and deploying it on Websphere I got an error which I will provide soon.
The Websphere version is 8.5.5.19 which has java 8_261.
Here is the error I am getting provided from SystemOut in websphere log.
ERROR --- [ebContainer : 0] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.micronaut.core.value.PropertyResolver
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398) 
        etc... 

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micronaut.core.value.PropertyResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:610)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:244)
        etc... 

ERROR 1720 --- [ebContainer : 0] c.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper: Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=WIN-SA38J7RQSJHNode01,version=8.5.5.19,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=WIN-SA38J7RQSJHNode01Cell,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: io.micronaut.core.value.PropertyResolver

What is tried is the following.
I went to my build.gradle which looks like this:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsGradlePluginVersion"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:2.6"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.3.0"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:3.4.7"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "ali"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"com.bertramlabs.asset-pipeline"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven{url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"}

}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-core"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-logging"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:async"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.11.Final"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:events"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:gsp"

    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:5.3.0'
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:4.0.0.M1'
    implementation 'org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.9.1'

    implementation 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'

    implementation 'org.jfree:jfreechart:1.5.5'

    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.9'

    implementation 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl:1.2'

    implementation group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'export', version: '2.0.0'

    implementation 'org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.3'


    implementation 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.3.3'

    implementation 'org.webjars:jquery:3.6.0'
    implementation 'org.webjars:jquery-ui:1.13.3'


    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtimeOnly "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.2.1-b05"
    runtimeOnly "com.h2database:h2"
    runtimeOnly "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtimeOnly "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    runtimeOnly "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:3.4.7"
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:9.2.1.jre8'
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testImplementation "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testImplementation "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testImplementation "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:4.0.0"
    testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:4.0.0"
    testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:4.0.0"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:4.0.0"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:4.0.0"
}

bootRun {
    ignoreExitValue true
    jvmArgs(
            '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always',
            '-noverify',
            '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
            '-Xmx1024m')
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    configure(groovyOptions) {
        forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-Xmx1024m']
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

webdriverBinaries {
    if (!System.getenv().containsKey('GITHUB_ACTIONS')) {
        chromedriver {
            version = '2.45.0'
            fallbackTo32Bit = true
        }
        geckodriver '0.30.0'
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "geb.env", System.getProperty('geb.env')
    systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/integrationTest")
    if (!System.getenv().containsKey('GITHUB_ACTIONS')) {
        systemProperty 'webdriver.chrome.driver', System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')
        systemProperty 'webdriver.gecko.driver', System.getProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver')
    } else {
        systemProperty 'webdriver.chrome.driver', "${System.getenv('CHROMEWEBDRIVER')}/chromedriver"
        systemProperty 'webdriver.gecko.driver', "${System.getenv('GECKOWEBDRIVER')}/geckodriver"
    }
}


assets {
    includes = ['**/*.js', '**/*.css']
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}


And added more micronaut dependencies
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject"

**I have also turned on intellij annotation processing ran the app locally and it worked.
Then compiled again into war file and deployed on websphere.
When I try to start the deployed app I get.**
[7/17/24 13:42:26:707 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:26.689 ERROR --- [ebContainer : 6] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.micronaut.core.value.PropertyResolver
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:730)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:96)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:770)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:605)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:244)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:944)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:889)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:135)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:872)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:872)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:872)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:858)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:872)
    at grails.util.Environment.resolveCurrentEnvironment(Environment.groovy:286)
    at grails.util.Environment.cacheCurrentEnvironment(Environment.groovy:312)
    at grails.util.Environment.getCurrent(Environment.groovy:279)
    at grails.util.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.groovy:127)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.configureEnvironment(GrailsApp.groovy:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:620)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1464)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:642)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1042)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1413)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2273)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5536)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5662)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:704)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1351)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1244)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:246)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:641)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1404)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:982)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:529)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:350)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4056)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micronaut.core.value.PropertyResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:610)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:244)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:944)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:889)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:135)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:872)
    ... 145 common frames omitted

[7/17/24 13:42:26:744 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:26.744 ERROR 6348 --- [ebContainer : 6] com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp           : SRVE0015E: Failure to initialize Web application reportes-0.1.war
[7/17/24 13:42:26:795 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:26.794  WARN 6348 --- [ebContainer : 6] c.i.w.r.c.DeployedApplicationImpl        : WSVR0206E: Module, reportes-0.1.war, of application, reportes-0_1_war.ear/deployments/reportes-0_1_war, failed to start
[7/17/24 13:42:26:800 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:26.800  WARN 6348 --- [ebContainer : 6] c.i.w.r.component.ApplicationMgrImpl     : WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, reportes-0_1_war
[7/17/24 13:42:26:801 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:26.800  WARN 6348 --- [ebContainer : 6] c.i.w.r.component.ApplicationMgrImpl     : WSVR0217I: Stopping application: reportes-0_1_war
[7/17/24 13:42:26:851 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:26.850  WARN 6348 --- [ebContainer : 6] c.i.w.r.component.ApplicationMgrImpl     : WSVR0220I: Application stopped: reportes-0_1_war
[7/17/24 13:42:26:855 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
[7/17/24 13:42:26:855 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
[7/17/24 13:42:26:860 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:26.859 ERROR 6348 --- [ebContainer : 6] c.i.w.r.c.CompositionUnitMgrImpl         : WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=reportes-0_1_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=reportes-0_1_war failed to start.
[7/17/24 13:42:26:949 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:26.949  WARN 6348 --- [ebContainer : 6] com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider        : FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_44c3b31e_24.07.17_13.42.26.8608283148406379864104.txt com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl 679
[7/17/24 13:42:26:950 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:26.949  INFO 6348 --- [ebContainer : 6] com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.DMAdapter           : FFDC1009I: Analysis Engine using data base: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\properties\logbr\ffdc\adv\ffdcdb.xml
[7/17/24 13:42:26:950 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:26.950  WARN 6348 --- [ebContainer : 6] com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider        : FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_44c3b31e_24.07.17_13.42.26.883666792781192245214.txt com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke 679
[7/17/24 13:42:26:950 TRT] 00000094 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:26.950 ERROR 6348 --- [ebContainer : 6] c.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper  : Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=WIN-SA38J7RQSJHNode01,version=8.5.5.19,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=WIN-SA38J7RQSJHNode01Cell,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: io.micronaut.core.value.PropertyResolver
[7/17/24 13:42:28:430 TRT] 00000091 SystemOut     O 2024-07-17 13:42:28.430  INFO 6348 --- [ebContainer : 3] c.i.w.w.servlet.ServletWrapper           : SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/secure/javascriptToSession.jsp]: Initialization successful.


Please Help I am Losing braincells

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.micronaut.core.value.PropertyResolver means that class PropertyResolver was successfully located when you compiled your Web application but it is not available when you start that application. The JAR file containing class PropertyResolver should either be in the WAR file or made accessible via WebSphere configuration. That's what you need to check.

What version of micronaut is it pulling in? There was a websphere fix in v3.8.11 https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/releases/tag/v3.8.11 which was also merged up into v3.9.7, v3.10.2 and v4.0.7

@Abra thanks for noting that.  I will update my post soon

@tim_yates I checked the contents of the war file. I found the following jars.
micronaut-aop-3.8.5.jar
micronaut-cache-core-3.5.0.jar
micronaut-context-3.8.5.jar
micronaut-core-3.8.5.jar
micronaut-core-reactive-3.8.5
micronaut-http-3.8.5.jar
micronaut-inject-3.8.5.jar
micronaut-jackson-core-3.8.5.jar
micronaut-jackson-databind-3.8.5.jar
micronaut-json-core-3.8.5.jar
micronaut-runtime-3.8.5.jar
micronaut-spring-4.5.0.jar
micronaut-spring-context-4.5.0.jar

Update:
I tried deploying my war on websphere version 9 instead of 8.
I got a different error
No bean of type [io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventPublisher<io.micronaut.context.event.StartupEvent>] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).

Think you'll need to use 3.8.11 for io.micronaut dependencies to get that fix

@tim_yates
Yes using micronaut 3.8.11 fixed the issue on websphere 9.
And concerning webshere 8.5.5 it seems that micronaut version 3.x is not compatible which explains the error.
My issue is solved
Thanks guys
